# "EACCES: permission denied, copyfile..." when starting Firebase emulator

Tags: firebase, macos, permissions, firebase-tools

Environment: MacOS 10.15.7

Running `firebase emulators:start` gave the following error in my firebase-debug.log:

```
EACCES: permission denied, copyfile '/var/folders/dc/jq6m586d0mngjdm2zlljtm740000gn/T/tmp-9821Nl0DY3zOWlHD.tmp' -> '/Users/[my_username]/.cache/firebase/emulators/ui-v1.7.0.zip'
```

My emulator quit starting up when it was downloading the UI. The following was the last step in my terminal window before the emulator started to shut down:

```
`i ui: downloading ui-v1.7.0.zip...`
```

Is there a way to grant Firebase permissions to download the UI to the correct location?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by running `sudo firebase emulators:start` to allow the firebase emulator UI to be downloaded to the correct location. After doing this, I am able to run `firebase emulators:start` without the `sudo` keyword as the UI has already been downloaded to the correct location.